# Shellcode executes in GDB but fails to execute in normal operation

Tags: security, gdb, stack-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I am working on a challenge that requires me to use x86 shellcode in order to gain access to a shell. The payload is delivered via `stdin` using either `./vuln <input` or `cat input |./vuln`.

When executing the program in GDB by invoking `start <input`, the exploit works and the shellcode executes all the way up to the `execve()` interrupt, leading me to believe that the shellcode is in fact working. However, when executing normally, I received a segfault and nothing else. When checking with `strace ./vuln <input`, I found that none of my shellcode ever actually runs.

For reference, the shellcode I am using is sourced from https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/13357, and I can confirm that each individual instruction executes when testing in GDB.

Why might this happen? GDB reports that a new process has been spawned, so why does it not work outside of GDB?

Comment: `I receive a segfault and nothing else` Did you reverse your shellcode? Might have to do with big/little endianness. Is your return address correct? Did you add a NOP sled so you're sure it hits the shellcode? There's a huge list of factors as to why it might have failed, check your registers to see what went wrong

Comment: @Paradoxis I did all of these things; the shellcode executes in order after a NOP sled, and every instruction is correct, which is what confuses me.

Comment: If you type `set disable-randomization off` to gdb before starting the program, do things work or fail?